# Upload .csv and change as.Date format in Shiny

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shinyapps, as.date

I am writing a shiny app that involves loading a .csv file and then display tables and graphs. One of the columns of the imported data needs to be in date format in order to work on further graphs. However, I am having issues to make this happen.

If I was working directly in RStudio, this is easy to make:

```
data_clean <- read.csv(input$file, header = input$header)

data_clean$date <- as.Date(data_clean$date) # converting date to date format
```

and it works perfectly.

But when I am doing it when I upload a .csv file through this code I have an error:

```
server <- function(input, output) {


# vals will contain all table and plot grobs
vals <- reactiveValues(table1=NULL, 
                       plot1=NULL, 
                       plot2=NULL,
                       plot3=NULL,
                       plot4=NULL,
                       plot5=NULL)  

updata <- eventReactive(input$file, {
  read.csv(input$file$datapath, header=TRUE) 
})


data <- eventReactive(updata, {

  updata$date <- as.Date(updata$date) # THIS IS MY PROBLEM

})

selectedDate <- eventReactive(input$clicks,{
    data() %>% 
     filter(date > input$datesel[1] & date < input$datesel[2])

    },
    ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$table1 <- renderTable(withProgress(message = 'loading summary table', value = 0.7, {
    vals$table1 <- selectedDate() %>% 
      group_by(PINNED) %>% 
      summarize(
        Records = n_distinct(record), 
        Specimens = (sum(count, na.rm = TRUE))-(sum(loaned_number, na.rm = TRUE)),  
        Species = n_distinct(species), 
        Hosts = n_distinct(host_or_trap),
        Countries = n_distinct(Country, na.rm = TRUE), 
        Localities = n_distinct(locality),
        Collectors = n_distinct(collector.museum),
        Loans = sum(loaned_number, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  })
  )}
```

When I run this it says: **Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable**

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Closures are functions. So somewhere in your code you are accidentally trying to subset a function. An example would be ˙summary[1]˙, which gives you an error, while `summary(1)[1]` gives you a subset of the output of the function . But it is hard to debug your code without any data. Please consult [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The part that I add and throws me an error is this:                                                 data <- eventReactive(updata, {

  updata$date <- as.Date(updata$date) 

}) If I don't try to change the format it works fine, the problem is that I don't know how to change the format while I am uploading a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
data <- eventReactive(updata, {
            updata() %>%
            mutate(date = as.Date(date))
})
```

It's similar to the code you already have (re: `selectedDate`) and doesn't involve subsetting `updata`.